# how to combine frequently used path pattern using "&" in spray

Tags: scala, spray

I am using spray to expose restful service. since there are common pattern in most service, so I using "&" to create alias for it. like following:

```
def getPath(path1: String) = path(path1) & get & detach() & complete
```

this code is written inside a trait MyService extends HttpService with Json4sSupport , if you try to compile it separately, you may have to write like this

```
def getPath(path1: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = path(path1) & spray.routing.Directives.get & detach() & complete
```

and use it is in route is easy:

```
~ getPath("person2") { xxx }  
//works as
//path("person1") {
//        get {
//          detach() {
//            complete {
//              println("receiving request /person1")
//              something
//            }
//          }
//        }
//      }
```

but I don't know how to create same alias for post:

```
path("account" / "transaction") {
        post {
          entity(as[TransferRequest]) { transferReq =>
            detach() {
              complete {
                //doing transfer
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I've tried

```
def postPath[T](path1: String) = path(path1) & post & entity(as[T]) & detach() & complete
```

but doesn't work , no where to get the "transferReq" parameter. 
how should I define to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`complete` is not a composable directive, take it out and you are all good. Try this

```
def postPath[T](path1: String)(implicit um:FromRequestUnmarshaller[T], ec: ExecutionContext): Directive1[T] = 
    path(path1) & post & entity(as[T]) & detach(())
```

then in your call site, use it like this

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

postPath[String]("123").apply { s =>
  complete (s + "abc")
}
```